# vim freezes with C-s within tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I have mapped Ctrl-s key to save a file in .vimrc. This was working fine till I just installed tmux. (Note that it was working fine because I had "stty -ixon" set in my .bashrc file).

How can I get the mapping work again when opening vim from tmux window?

What I tried so far without success:

1. Added `stty -ixon` in `.bashrc`
2. Added `stty stop undef` in `.bashrc`
3. Added both 1 and 2 in `.bashrc`
4. Added `unbind-key C-s` in `.tmux.conf`

Comment: Does tmux intercept Ctrl-S? This must be documented somewhere. Can you change tmux keybinds?  I bet that's also documented....

Comment: @Useless I thought the same earlier and had tried "unbind-key C-s" in .tmux.conf but didn't help.

Comment: If you've done some research and tried some things already, could you say what you've found, and what you tried unsuccessfully in your question? Otherwise you're going to waste lots of time - both yours and everyone else's.

Comment: Apologies @Useless. Let me add that

Comment: does terminal output freeze with C-s in tmux when not in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @jeremysprofile for the suggestion. Here is the solution that fixed my issue for future references:

tmux was working fine outside of vim for C-s. So, instead of opening vim straight by 'tmux new-window -n editor vim', I did 'tmux new-window -n editor bash' and then 'tmux send-keys -t my_sess:editor "vim" C-m'.

The reason above works is because now vim is opened under bash(which invokes the .bashrc prior to calling vim).